# SOAP/REST calls over XMPP

Tags: http, rest, soap, xmpp, chat

I want to make a solution where I can use XMPP chat clients connected to gtalk, resolving SOAP web services and REST calls meant for a LAN (behind firewall proxy etc) and transferring over to the other chat client on another different LAN (behind other firewall proxy etc).

I have narrowed down on [Smack API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp), but being a newbie in XMPP and smack, I don't know if is it possible or not with Smack?

Does smack provide for such a functionality? I tried Smack documentation but couldn't understand it in enough depth.

Any other possible alternatives, suggestions too are most welcome.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to tunnel HTTP over XMPP to avoid firewalls?

Comment: yes, you are right Darrel, please suggest your opinion about it.

Comment: Be aware that REST makes no sense over XMPP (it's very strongly coupled to HTTP) but SOAP is perfectly sane.

Comment: @DonalFellows: no, REST is NOT coupled with HTTP.  Please read Dr. Fielding's thesis again, it explicitly states that.  In fact, all of the attributes of REST can be accomplished in XMPP with careful protocol design.  However, it doesn't really matter, because the OP can accomplish what he actually desired without having to make an ontological decision on protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with [XEP-72](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0072.html) for a hint at the style of protocol you should use.  There are some good reasons to do this, including:

- Firewall traversal (as noted)
- Don't have to do a TCP connection as often, saving latency
- Don't have to authenticate for each request, but can authenticate the stream
- No need for a separate XML parser for each request, which means processing can be more efficient

Answer (score 2):

To make things easier start with http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html and use command's node attribute in a restfull way